# How to concatenate numbers in c++/CLR

Tags: c++-cli

I have a variable `num1`.

Now I would like to concatenate a number to `num1`

Example -> `num1 += 5;`

Rather than concatenating like expected, it sets `num1` as 0. Same goes for `num2`

This is my part of code that should set `num1` or `num2` as 5:

```
private: System::Void button14_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    if (label1->Text == "Operator")
    {
        if (label3->Text == "Result")
            label3->Text = gcnew String("5");
        else
            label3->Text += gcnew String("5");
        to_string(num1) += "5";
    }
    else if (label1->Text != "Operator")
    {
        label3->Text += gcnew String("5");
        to_string(num2) += "5";
    }
}
```

This is the `=` button

```
private: System::Void button23_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    if (label1->Text != "Operator")
    {
        if (label1->Text == "+")
        {
            result = num1 + num2;
            label3->Text = gcnew String(to_string(result).data());
        }
        else if (label1->Text == "-")
        {
            result = num1 - num2;
            label3->Text = gcnew String(to_string(result).data());
        }
        else if (label1->Text == "x")
        {
            result = num1 * num2;
            label3->Text = gcnew String(to_string(result).data());
        }
        else if (label1->Text == "÷")
        {
            float(result) = num1 / num2;
            label3->Text = gcnew String(to_string(result).data());
        }
        else if (label1->Text == "%")
        {
            float(result) = num1 / num2 * 100;
            label3->Text = gcnew String(to_string(result).data());
        }
        else if (label1->Text == "Power")
        {
            result = pow(num1, num2);
            label3->Text = gcnew String(to_string(result).data());
        }
        else if (label1->Text == "Square Root")
        {
            result = sqrt(num1);
            label3->Text = gcnew String(to_string(result).data());
        }
        else if (label1->Text == "Cube Root")
        {
            result = cbrt(num1);
            label3->Text = gcnew String(to_string(result).data());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        label1->Text = "Please make sure you complete the equation(put 0 as";
        label3->Text = "2nd number for root)";
    }
}
```

Comment: `num1 = num1 * 10 + 5;`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`num1 += 6` is the same as `num1 = num1 + 6` so, if `num1` is 5, it is the same as `num1 = 5 + 6`, and as you probably know, 5 + 6 is 11.

`to_string(num1) += "5";` has no effect on `num`; it creates a string, modifies it, and then throws it away.

You need to use the Ancient Power of Mathematics: `num = num * 10 + 5;`

Comment: but what if I need to press `button14` again? so to get 565 + 56